# Add each column with last value of last column of the row in dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to add each column of dataframe with the last column of the row in R.
My dataframe-

```
L   E   B1  P   B2  M   Value
5   5   0   20  2   5   100
10  6   0   40  15  2   150
6   15  0   50  6   10  160
1   10  0   55  5   20  160
0   20  0   80  0   20  200
10  1   20  80  10  10  250
8   2   40  30  5   10  300
5   3   60  30  5   20  350
5   4   30  75  5   20  400
1   0   50  80  0   10  400
2   0   40  60  5   20  500
0   0   60  50  0   30  500
```

So 1st row will be like-

```
L   E   B1  P   B2  M   Value
5*100   5*100   0*100   20*100  2*100   5*100   100
10  6   0   40  15  2   150
6   15  0   50  6   10  160
1   10  0   55  5   20  160
0   20  0   80  0   20  200
10  1   20  80  10  10  250
8   2   40  30  5   10  300
5   3   60  30  5   20  350
5   4   30  75  5   20  400
1   0   50  80  0   10  400
2   0   40  60  5   20  500
0   0   60  50  0   30  500
```

I tried to use lapply

```
lapply(df1, function(x) x * tail(x,1) )
```

But it takes the row value , so how to get each row last column value or any specific column to add with all other column values in R

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not clear if you want to multiply or divide (there seems to be a contradiction between what you ask for and your own attempt) but here's an approach for multiplication:

```
cbind(mydf[-length(mydf)] * mydf[[length(mydf)]], mydf[length(mydf)])
#       L    E    B1     P   B2     M Value
# 1   500  500     0  2000  200   500   100
# 2  1500  900     0  6000 2250   300   150
# 3   960 2400     0  8000  960  1600   160
# 4   160 1600     0  8800  800  3200   160
# 5     0 4000     0 16000    0  4000   200
# 6  2500  250  5000 20000 2500  2500   250
# 7  2400  600 12000  9000 1500  3000   300
# 8  1750 1050 21000 10500 1750  7000   350
# 9  2000 1600 12000 30000 2000  8000   400
# 10  400    0 20000 32000    0  4000   400
# 11 1000    0 20000 30000 2500 10000   500
# 12    0    0 30000 25000    0 15000   500
```

The basic idea is to just multiply all the columns except for the last one by the values in the last column. Since that column has been dropped, you add it back in with `cbind`.

Answer (score 7):

Using dplyr and assuming your dataframe is df:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate_each(funs(. * Value), -Value)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's another base R option:

```
n <- ncol(df)
df[-n] <- df[-n] * df[[n]]
```

*Note: running this code will modify your existing data.frame. If you want to create a new data.frame and keep the old one as is, you'd better use the answer by Ananda Mahto or one of the others.*

Comment: Nice one. This is what I would do

Comment: @akrun, "almost similar" implies that it's not the same. Main difference from my point of view is that I avoid using `cbind`.

Comment: @akrun, the main difference is not `cbind`, rather the fact that he is updating `df` on the fly rather than creating some new data set in the global environment. Kind of reminds me the logic behind update by reference in `data.table`

Comment: I'm guessing this is related to the similarity with my answer, but it seems like there's a comment missing from the discussion. This is a technique I would use in my own code, but not sure how often I would recommend it to users who don't seem to be as experienced with R. I can easily see a follow up "Where did my original data go?" type of question. Anyway, it's always nice to have options around.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, I agree that there might be a follow up question but in this case I'd argue that the OP is a "software developer" and at least not a first time user on SO, so seems to have some knowledge about programming and secondly, I think the learning even if asking a follow up question, would be quite useful because this way he could learn how more experienced R users like you would actually approach this problem. Last but not least, I agree that it's nice to have different options which is another reason I posted this answer.

Comment: @docendodiscimus   I got confused (gave you +1).  It's better to clear so I commented.  I think you have a valid point based on the comments from others too.  Why I stressed is because I found in some posts, people does come up with `transform`, then `within` as separate solutions.  Here, it is not that issue.  Please do not delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Just to complete the picture, you could also update the data by reference using `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, names(df)[-length(df)] := 
            lapply(.SD, "*", df$Value), 
            .SDcols = -"Value"]
df
#        L    E    B1     P   B2     M Value
#  1:  500  500     0  2000  200   500   100
#  2: 1500  900     0  6000 2250   300   150
#  3:  960 2400     0  8000  960  1600   160
#  4:  160 1600     0  8800  800  3200   160
#  5:    0 4000     0 16000    0  4000   200
#  6: 2500  250  5000 20000 2500  2500   250
#  7: 2400  600 12000  9000 1500  3000   300
#  8: 1750 1050 21000 10500 1750  7000   350
#  9: 2000 1600 12000 30000 2000  8000   400
# 10:  400    0 20000 32000    0  4000   400
# 11: 1000    0 20000 30000 2500 10000   500
# 12:    0    0 30000 25000    0 15000   500
```

Comment: I was trying this too.  After `DT <- as.data.table(df)` I did `val <- DT[,Value]; DT[, names(DF)[-7] := .SD * val, .SDcols = -"Value"]`.  Which one do you think is better?  Or does it matter?  I did `tracemem` and didn't see any copying being made

Comment: Its the same I guess, your version would be faster due saving the `$` part. I just wanted to everything in one step.